# What is the most appropriate way to achieve synchronous Addressable asset loading?

Tags: unity

I am transitioning my project from `Resources` to `Addressables`. Some parts of my game just aren't worth doing asynchronously, and would just cause more problems - but I still want to use `Addressables` for its other benefits.

Anyway, it doesn't offer any synchronous methods in their API. Unity has an official repository with an example for "synchronous addressables" right here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Addressables-Sample/blob/master/Advanced/Sync%20Addressables/Assets/SyncAddressables/SyncAddressables.cs

<s>Although the code does appear to work in the few tests I've done</s> The code below won't always work, and it doesn't make sense to me anyway. This is the relevant method:

```
    public static TObject LoadAsset<TObject>(object key)
    {
        if(!s_Initialized)
            throw new Exception("Whoa there friend!  We haven't init'd yet!");

        var op = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<TObject>(key);        

        if(!op.IsDone)
            throw new Exception("Sync LoadAsset failed to load in a sync way! " + key);

        if (op.Result == null)
        {
            var message = "Sync LoadAsset has null result " + key;
            if (op.OperationException != null)
                message += " Exception: " + op.OperationException;

            throw new Exception(message);
        }

        return op.Result;
    }
```

It will throw an exception if the asset didn't manage to load instantly (the `!op.isDone` part). Sure, that's technically synchronous, but it seems to ignore the elephant in the room: if the asset is large I would expect it to need a bit more time (i.e. freeze the game), which is fine for my current needs - but instead, the game will just end up crashing because it couldn't load immediately.

What is the most appropriate way to achieve synchronous Addressable asset loading?

Comment: Maybe it run synchronously inside the editor. Have you tried to create a build and run the executable, APK or whatever your target is?

Comment: From my understanding, the Addressables runs concurrently in the background, possibly on a separate thread, so you might be lucky or not with the code you posted. I would highly not recommend to deploy that code in production as you cannot guarantee how it will behave.

I guess the easiest would be to load all your assets into some sort of "cache" or object pool and only start your game when they are all available. That way you don't have to deal with asynchronous calls, but that kind of defeat the purpose of Addressables.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on what your application does, you could use "place holder" objects with the same properties that are NOT Addressables to keep the state of the object while they are loading (and possibly display something for the user to indicate that it is busy). Then when the Addressable is done, you update the new object with the "place holder" state and Destroy the "place holder".

Comment: @JasperCiti you're correct, it doesn't always work. I was just lucky I guess.